# What happens to mysql queries if php file timeouts?

Tags: php, mysql, server

I have a website that runs really long queries, because it's kind of a popular browser game.

I run a untested, but very promising (that it will work) php file that alters my SQL data. It's working but php file timed out. But looking to SSH, I'm seeing that query is still running.

But my php file is based on a query's response and an another query that uses the response data.

What will happen now?

I'm having a heart attack right now while waiting the end result. And I'm really high.

Will it work properly even its' related php file timed out?

Comment: php sends query, db then runs query, db does not care what php is doing

Comment: @Dagon is correct, if all the request was already sent, even if php timesout, you should be ok. Next time use workbench for big onetimes.

Comment: Better start by seeking medical attention. Heart attacks are the benchmark of seriousness.

Comment: @Dagon but what another query  use response data from the first query?

Answer (score 2):

The PHP is timed out, so it will not continue past the query. The query will however finish.

Sidenote: You can fix this in the future by having a set_time_limit(0);(http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)